# Finding $E(X \mid X > Y )$ when $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is the problem:

> The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $N(0,1)$-distributed.
>   Determine
>
> 1. $E(X \mid X > Y )$,
> 2. $E(X + Y \mid  X > Y )$.

I go by the definition of $$f_{X \mid X>Y}(x) = \frac{\int_x^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,t)dt}{f_X(x)}= \cdots = (2\pi)^{-1/2} \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2} dt$$ but that function does not have a primitive. I thought about "getting" a Gamma under the int but I'm not sure on how to proceed here.

---

Edit 1. I got the following tip. If $(X,Y)$ is normal centered, there exists some nonnegative $(\sigma,\tau,\varrho)$ and $(U,V)$ i.i.d. standard normal such that $X-Y=\sigma U$ and $X=\tau U+\varrho V$. Thus, $$E(X\mid X\gt Y)=\tau E(U\mid U\gt0)+\varrho E(V\mid U\gt0)==\frac{2\tau}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$ But I do not see why the == is true. I also don't know how this would help me, do I pick $\tau$ and  $\varrho$ to be 1?

Comment: $\displaystyle (2\pi)^{-1/2} \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2} dt$ does not look like a (conditional) probability density, as its integral is infinite.

Comment: There are easier ways to proceed, but it is possible to work with the conditional density. The ultimate conditional density expression you got is not quite right. If it is corrected, the expectation can be found by integration by parts. Question b) is much simpler.

Comment: Do you ever cite the pages from where you copy some passages?

Comment: @Did Cite what?

Comment: `the pages from where you copy some passages` (bis).

Comment: @Did It's a problem from class, what do you want me to cite?

Comment: As you are well aware, your Edit 1 is reproducing without  attribution a contribution to another page of another user. Omitting a link to the page and an explicit mention of the fact is not acceptable.

Comment: @did Would you mind helping me understand how the other question answers this one?  The other question is bivariate normal; this one is two independent normal distributions.  Does that restriction not permit a simpler answer?  I'm not sure, but I would have liked to find out.  Also, I do not see an answer to part 2 at the other question, so I'm not sure it should have been marked as duplicate in any case.

Answer (score 0):

For $E(X + Y \mid X > Y)$, you can simply relabel $X, Y$ so that $X$ is almost surely greater than $Y$ without changing what you're taking the expectation of (and $P(X=Y) = 0$), so

$$E(X + Y \mid X > Y) = E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y) = 0$$